# Downloading Files added into database in Angularjs and Spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am facing an issue while downloading the file added into the database. I am using AngularJS and Spring MVC architecture.
In a table I am displaying filenames I have added.

Here is my html

fee.html

```
    <td><a href="./filedownload/{{fee.fileName}}/feespath">
    {{fee.fileName}}</a></td>
```

Here is Spring Controller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/filedownload/{fileName:.+}/{path}",method=
    {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public void filedownload(@PathVariable String 
    fileName,@PathVariable String path,HttpServletResponse response)
    {
    Path file = Paths.get(context.getRealPath("/"+path+"/"),
    fileName);
    if (Files.exists(file)) 
    {
        response.setContentType("*/*");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;
        filename="+fileName);
    try
    {
        Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
```

And while adding I am using "feespath" as the path name that I am using in my html. Here is how I am creating a path by name feespath

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadFeeFiles",method=
    {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public @ResponseBody String uploadFeeFiles(HttpServletRequest 
    request,HttpServletResponse response,MultipartHttpServletRequest 
    mRequest,Principal principal)
    {
        String status="";
    try
    {
        mRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        mRequest.getParameterMap();
        Iterator<String> itr = mRequest.getFileNames();
    while (itr.hasNext()) 
    {
        MultipartFile file = mRequest.getFile(itr.next());
        String fileName = 
        uploadPathService.getFilesPath(file,"feespath");
        status = fileName;
    }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return status;
    }
```

I am able to display file names correctly in the table but if I click on it it's redirecting to a blank page with url

http://localhost:8080/MyProject/filedownload/12802889_1263849593630301.jpg/feespath

So I am not able to figure it out. If anyone can introduce some ideas, I'll be very helpful.

Comment: Never 'hack and paste' urls in Angular. use specific directives such as `ng-href`. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).

Comment: I used ng-href but same issue